# Drop shadows to the div using images

Tags: css

I am working on a div which should show a drop shadow at the bottom and right. Here is the link to the html page. I dont know why the classes are not getting applied to the div. Your help is highly appreciated.
[Tooltip.html](http://shivanand.in/forums/tooltip/tooltip.html)

Here is the image mock-up which shows the Drop shadow affect
[Image-mockup](http://shivanand.in/forums/tooltip/Image-mockup.png)

Answer (score 1):

**[This might help...](http://sarfraznawaz.wordpress.com/2010/03/16/drop-shadow-effect-with-four-lines-of-jquery-code/)**

Comment: I am looking for CSS solution and not Jquery

Answer (score 1):

You can also drew shadows using css3 in the browser that supported it. Like:

```
-moz-box-shadow
```

Comment: and don't forget `-webkit-border-radius:5px;`

Comment: IE even 8 don't support css3.